# Remove Bootstrap 4 button outline Mixin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Honestly, I have no idea how to write this to work. I want a sass mixin that would remove that blue Bootstrap outline every button tends to have, so I can just add it to buttons I want as I go along.

Could someone possibly help me with this one?
I've tried a few approaches, but they basically do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would have something like this:

```css
@mixin outline($value) {
    outline: $value;
}
button {
  @include outline(0);
}
```

which outputs:

```css
button {
  outline: 0;
}
```

see a demo [**here**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b4ec9537a8c8cd6b24b2ea5ec434778c)

Comment: Thank you, dippas !

Answer (score 3):

You could set the SCSS variable like so:

```
$btn-focus-width: 0;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I was looking for.